# How to keep dropping the first value, until the sum of the vector is less than 20?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I am looking for a function which takes a vector and keeps dropping the first value until the sum of the vector is less than 20. Return the remaining values.

I've tried both a for-loop and while-loop and can't find a solution.

```
vec <- c(3,5,3,4,3,9,1,8,2,5)

short <- function(vec){

 for (i in 1:length(vec)){
    while (!is.na((sum(vec)) < 20)){
      vec <- vec[i+1:length(vec)]
      #vec.remove(i)
  }
}
```

The expected output should be:
`1,8,2,5`
which is less than 20.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the expected output it looks like you want to drop values until sum of remaining values is less than 20.

We can create a function

```
drop_20 <- function(vec) {
  tail(vec, sum(cumsum(rev(vec)) < 20))
}

drop_20(vec)
#[1] 1 8 2 5
```

Trying it on another input

```
drop_20(1:10)
#[1]  9 10
```

---

Breaking down the function, first the `vec`

```
vec = c(3,5,3,4,3,9,1,8,2,5)
```

We then `rev`erse it

```
rev(vec)
#[1] 5 2 8 1 9 3 4 3 5 3
```

take cumulative sum over it (`cumsum`)

```
cumsum(vec)
#[1]  3  8 11 15 18 27 28 36 38 43
```

Find out number of enteries that are less than 20

```
cumsum(rev(vec)) < 20
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

sum(cumsum(rev(vec)) < 20)
#[1] 4
```

and finally subset these last enteries using `tail`.

---

A slight modification in the code and it should be able to handle `NA`s as well

```
drop_20 <- function(vec) {
   tail(vec, sum(cumsum(replace(rev(vec), is.na(rev(vec)), 0)) < 20))
}

vec = c(3, 2, NA, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NA, 1, 2)
drop_20(vec)
#[1]  3  4  9 NA  1  2
```

The logic being we `replace` `NA` with zeroes and then take the `cumsum`

Comment: I think this is the fastest solution so far which of course matters only on a larger vector.

Comment: @Phann or one a large number of small vectors :).

Comment: FYI, you should also handle NA's somewhere in there. Good idea btw :)

Comment: I don't know why but when I tried your code, the output is     integer(0)

Comment: @HannaDup must be because of `NA`s you may take a look at the updated answer now.

Comment: Another along the same lines: `tail(vec, - findInterval(0, cumsum(vec) - 20) - 1L)`... which requires that vec >= 0

Comment: @Frank hmm..look interesting. But how would it handle `NA`s ? For `vec = c(3, 2, NA, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NA, 1, 2)` it didn't give the right answer. I tried to `replace` `NA`s with 0 `tail(vec, -findInterval(0, cumsum(replace(vec, is.na(vec), 0)) - 20) - 1L)` but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Ronak Hm, yeah, I'm not sure how to extend to that case.

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the first value each time, so your `while` loop should be,

```
while (sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) >= 20) {
    x <- x[-1]
}

#[1] 1 8 2 5
```

Comment: From the OP's post, might look like their actual data has NA's in it? If so, remember to  define `sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Good eye! Thanks

Comment: Not downvoted, but the quadratic behavior (not sure how `x <- x[-1]` behaves in R, so possibly worse) of something that's pretty easy to do linearly might be the reason.

Comment: @Voo I m not sure what you mean by quadratic/linear (I do know the math). I assume that you mean the `while` loop Vs not needing `while`. Even If this is the case, the downvote is still biased as I followed the OPs train of thought in order to show the mistake. It is a bad downvote, however one looks at this. Also `x <- x[-1]` is just removing the first value...no complex behavior

Comment: @Sotos It's not the while loop per se, but the interaction between sums, while loop and the removal. I would expect "Just removing the first value" to be O(N) assuming an array of kinds which would cause the whole behavior to be O(N^3) instead of O(N). Now I'm not saying that it's always bad (simple code is often fine even if it's orders of magnitudes slower than it has to be), but I can understand why someone would downvote such a solution that doesn't make note of that behavior.

Answer (score 6):

base solution without loops
not my most readable code ever, but it's pretty fast (see benchmarking below)

```
rev( rev(vec)[cumsum( replace( rev(vec), is.na( rev(vec) ), 0 ) ) < 20] )
#[1] 1 8 2 5
```

note: 'borrowed' the `NA`-handling from @Ronak's answer

**sample data**
`vec = c(3, 2, NA, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NA, 1, 2)`

**benchmarks**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Sotos = { 
    while (sum(vec, na.rm = TRUE) >= 20) {
      vec <- vec[-1] 
    } 
  },
  Ronak = tail(vec, sum(cumsum(replace(rev(vec), is.na(rev(vec)), 0)) < 20)),
  Wimpel = rev( rev(vec)[cumsum( replace( rev(vec), is.na( rev(vec) ), 0 ) ) < 20]),
  WimpelMarkus = vec[rev(cumsum(rev(replace(vec, is.na(vec), 0))) < 20)]
  )


# Unit: microseconds
#         expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#        Sotos 2096.795 2127.373 2288.15768 2152.6795 2425.4740 3071.684   100
#        Ronak   30.127   33.440   42.54770   37.2055   49.4080  101.827   100
#       Wimpel   13.557   15.063   17.65734   16.1175   18.5285   38.261   100
# WimpelMarkus    7.532    8.737   12.60520   10.0925   15.9680   45.491   100
```

Comment: I think you can save a couple of `rev`'s here: `vec[rev(cumsum(rev(replace(vec, is.na(vec), 0))) < 20)]`. This might give a further speed-up.

Comment: @markus you are very very right.. I was a bit too lazy in the copy-pasting I guess... you just reduced execution time with 30-40%! (see updated benchmarks in answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `Reduce`

```
vec[Reduce(f = "+", x = vec, accumulate = T, right = T) < 20]
##[1] 1 8 2 5
```

Alternatively, define Reduce with  function `sum` with the conditional argument `na.rm = T` in order to hanlde NAs if desired:

```
vec2 <- c(3, 2, NA, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, NA, 1, 2)
vec2[Reduce(f = function(a,b) sum(a, b, na.rm = T), x = vec2, accumulate = TRUE, right = T) < 20]
##[1]  3  4  9 NA  1  2
```

I find the Reduce option to start from right (end of the integer vector), and hence not having to reverse it first, convenient.